# Knockout calls subscribe function before rendering the view

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

Knockout is calling subscribe function before rendering the view even without `beforechange` attribute, when used with `arrayChange` param.

I have created JSfiddle because StackOverflow ignores `debugger;` keyword in JavaScript code, and that is the easiest way to see this behavior.
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayfhcdt/26/)

Is there any way to signal KnockOut to call subscribe function after render?

I need to do this with subscribe, it is used by a custom bind and can not be invoked by `afterRender` or similar view handling functions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing. When running the fiddle, nothing is logged. When pressing "PUSH", the console first logs `SUBSCRIBE` and then logs `PUSH` (as you would expect).

Comment: Please use Chrome web browser or any other that supports `debugger;` keyword. When "PUSH" is pressed the debugger holds on the subscribe step where the "SUBSCRIBE" is printed out, but `items` element is not rendered yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could expose a method on your view model to create the subscription, then call it on the vm after calling ko.applyBindings:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.push = function(){
      self.items.push((Math.random(10)*10).toFixed(0));
      console.log("PUSH");
    }

    this.subscribeAfterApply = function(){
      this.items.subscribe(changes=>{
        console.log("SUBSCRIPTION FIRED");
      }, null, "arrayChange");
      console.log("SUBSCRIBED");
    }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.subscribeAfterApply();
```

Comment: Hi, this actually does not solve my problem because I need it to be called inside globally used custom bind. But it gave me the direction to think about, so thank you very much!